# Parse With Swift: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key submit.'

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

UPDATE:

Figured it out, I was using weak variables instead of strong

I'm trying learn how to use parse with swift.  I made a basic app that has a registration form that pushes the registration data to parse.  However, I'm getting an error upon running the app.

This is the view controller where I'm having the error

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var user: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var pass: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func submit(sender: AnyObject) {

        var account:PFUser = PFUser()
        account.username = user.text
        account.password = pass.text

        account.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock{
            (success:Bool!, error:NSError!)->Void in
            if !(error != nil){
                println("Sign Up Successful")
            } else {
                println("Failure")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check interface builder and unattach whatever `submit` is attached to

Comment: Since you have found the answer yourself, you should either 1) answer your own question and accept the answer or 2) remove the question altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Change weak variables to strong variables

Comment: In its current form, this answer is unlikely to be helpful to anyone else.  Can you provide additional details?